# Using Excel worksheet as Excel Add-in

Tags: excel, vba, add-in

I have developed, (using Visual Studio 2015, as Excel 2013 Workbook) a simple Ribbon for Excel with some functions useful for my daily work.

The problem is not the code, but the following: I want to use that workbook as an add-in that could be installed in another Excel 2013, but I dont know if that is possible or I have to re-do the entire project as "Excel 2013 Add-in"

I have tried to save the workbook as Add-in and to install it from Excel, but even if the Ribbon is showing, most of the function won`t work (no error, but they do nothing)

Is it possible to make this "conversion" from worksheet to Add-in?

Comment: Just saving as addin won't be enought because you have developed a VSTO solution. Therefore you should create a setup or publish it via click once and then you can install the solution on another computer.

Comment: Thank you Peter, you're right. Now I'm running into a different problem, as I have installed the customization (via publishing the solution and using the setup), but I am not able to see the Ribbon when opening Excel, and it is not showing as Add-in in Options -> Add-ins. Am I missing something more?

Comment: VSTO solutions are generally more work to get everything right. If you can convert your functions to VBA, you might use the Custom UI Editor to add the ribbon and save the Excel File as Addin. Then you even don't need a setup... you end up by just having one file, containing the macros and ribbon.

Comment: Thank you Peter, I will look into this matter as it seems that I was choosing the wrong approach